# Convert nvarchar to datetime for date range query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My GLD (GL account) table includes Year and Period columns, both nvarchar types.

My purpose is to allow a user to select a range of dates in the query.  For example, to search...

- inpYearBegin: 2013
- inpPeriodBegin: 3
- inpYearEnd: 2014
- inpPeriodEnd: 12

But what ends up happening is that the results will not show periods 1 through 2 of 2014.  I presume I need to convert the fields to datetime, but I'm not sure where to go from there.  My SQL server query thus far:

```
Select GLD.GLD_EndingBalance,
  GLD.GLD_AcctNbr,
  GLD.GLD_Year,
  GLD.GLD_Period,
  Year(Cast(GLD.GLD_Year As DateTime)) As Year
From GLD
Where GLD.GLD_AcctNbr = '140000'
And GLD.GLD_Year >= '@Request.inpYearBegin~'
And GLD.GLD_Period >= '@Request.inpPeriodBegin~'
And GLD.GLD_Year <= '@Request.inpYearEnd~'
And GLD.GLD_Period <= '@Request.inpPeriodEnd~'
```

Comment: What RDBMS? These conversion functions are different for every vendor.

Comment: Looks like SQL Server. But you should tell and not let us guess.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: it is SQL server; post edited.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is tweak the `where` clause a bit and add some parentheses to control the comparison, something like this:

```
declare @FromYear  int = 2013
declare @FromMonth int =    3
declare @ThruYear  int = 2014
declare @ThruMonth int =   12

select t.GLD_EndingBalance ,
       t.GLD_AcctNbr       ,
       t.GLD_Year          ,
       t.GLD_Period        ,
       Year( Cast(GLD.GLD_Year As DateTime) ) as Year
from GLD t
where t.GLD_AcctNbr = '140000'
  and        t.GLD_Year between @FromYear and @ThruYear 
  and (      t.GLD_Year > @FromYear                                  
        OR   t.GLD_Year < @ThruYear                                  
        OR ( t.GLD_Year = @FromYear and t.GLD_Period >= @FromMonth ) 
        OR ( t.GLD_Year = @ThruYear and t.GLD_Period <= @ThruMonth )
      )
```

The above should return rows from March 2013 through December 2014, inclusive.

Another way to get there would be to use discriminent functions like so:

```
select t.GLD_EndingBalance ,
       t.GLD_AcctNbr       ,
       t.GLD_Year          ,
       t.GLD_Period        ,
       Year( Cast(GLD.GLD_Year As DateTime) ) as Year
from GLD t
where t.GLD_AcctNbr = '140000'
  and t.GLD_Year between @FromYear and @ThruYear 
  and t.GLD_Period between case when t.GLD_YEar = @FromYear then @FromMonth else  1 end
                       and case when t.GLD_YEAR = @ThruYear then @ThruMonth else 12 end
```

That simplifies the query, though I couldn't really say one is easier to comprehend than the other.

Perhaps more importantly, though: it might (emphasis on the *might*) get you a better execution plan.